# Building flutter app on iOS simulator failed

Tags: xcode, flutter, ios-simulator, macos-catalina

I've been developing a flutter app for android for quite some time now, decided to try building it for iOS on a Macbook Pro with M1 Pro chip. Everytime I run it, it works on running pod install and running Xcode build, but always fails at building iOS app. I tried creating a completely new project and run it on my iOS simulator and it worked. Been trying out solutions I could find but none of them worked. Here's the error I get:

```
xcodebuild[24755:304662] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore

xcodebuild[24755:304662] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
```

and at the end it shows this:

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was upgrade all my packages to the latest version, so I did. After resolving some errors caused by upgrading, I was finally able to install my iOS application.

Answer (score 0):

**Just replace this lines at the end of your Podfile**

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ARCHS'] = 'armv7 armv7s'
    end
  end
end
```

Flutter > ios > Podfile

Comment: Do you mean add not replace? Cause I don't see any installer_representation on my podfile, there is only post_install do |installer|

Comment: I tried adding it instead of replacing, didn't work, it says there can only be one post_install, so I added the config.build_settings['ARCHS] = 'armv7 armv7s' on my previous configuration, still didn't work

Comment: don't add just replace last paragraph in your pod file